# Problems with RSelenium and ChromeDriver - "Could not open chrome browser"

Tags: r, google-chrome, web-scraping, rselenium

I have been using `RSelenium` for years and have never had this issue. I recently updated my google chrome to the latest version available `110.0.5481.78`. I am now getting the following error when I go to use `rsDriver`

```R
require(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome",port = 9537L, chromever = "110.0.5481.77")
```

```R
"> Could not open chrome browser.
> Client error message:
> Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 9537: Connection refused
> Check server log for further details.
> Warning message:
> In rsDriver(browser = "chrome", port = 9537L, chromever = "110.0.5481.77") :
> Could not determine server status."
```

[R Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlin0.png)

I have tried with different versions of `chromever` from `binman::list_versions("chromedriver")` as well as leaving `rsDriver` blank all together. In the past when chrome has updated it has been a very simple change to `chromever` and everything works perfectly. Not sure if or what has changed with this latest update.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this same problem by removing a file LICENSE.chromedriver as per this thread: https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/264

Use

```
wdman::selenium(retcommand=T)
```

to find the file location of binman_chromedriver files.

Navigate to this file location, go to the driver version you're using and delete the LICENSE.chromedriver file. Mine worked immediately after this action, but note that I also tried downgading wdman version to 0.2.5 (I was on 0.2.6) first:

```
remotes::install_version('wdman',version = '0.2.5')
```

I'm not sure if it was both actions that fixed it or just the file delete!

Comment: This was the fix for me! Only need the first portion and did not need to downgrade wdman. Thank you